# Stat test to compare two sets of binomial data

Tags: contingency-tables, minitab

I am doing my undergraduate project and have tested a drug on cells for a responce. The data I have collected shows that the cells either produced a responce, or they did not. Binomial data?

```
Control 0ug/mL      22  3053
Control2 (DMSO)     15  2807
5ug/mL rapamycin    12  3070
10ug/mL rapamycin   7   2806
```

The first number is the number of cells that produced the responce, and the second number is the total number of cells tested.

I'm trying to work out the test I can use to see if the results between the groups are significant. I was think a Fisher's exact test, but I wasn't sure if that was just for 2x2 tables. Would a chi sq test be sufficient?

Answer (score 6):

In R, you can use

```
prop.test(x=c(22, 15, 12, 7), n=c(3053, 2807, 3070, 2806))
```

to compare the four proportions. Or as you noted, a $\chi^2$-Test can also be used:

```
m <- matrix(c(22, 15, 12, 7, 3053-22, 2807-15, 3070-12, 2806-7), 2, 4, byrow=T)
chisq.test(m)
```

The results are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a logistic regression.

```
dat.text <- "Treatment x n
Control1      22  3053
Control2     15  2807
5ug    12  3070
10ug   7   2806"

dat <- read.table(text=dat.text,header=TRUE)

fit <- glm(cbind(x,n-x)~0+Treatment, data=dat, family="binomial")
summary(fit)
```

Then use the `multcomp` package to get confidence intervals and multiple comparisons:

```
library(multcomp)
plot(confint(glht(fit)))  # confidence intervals of logit(p)
```

The `lsmeans` package is useful too. It has a convenient syntax for multiple comparisons:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(fit, pairwise~Treatment)
```

Actually it is interesting to jointly use `multcomp`and `lsmeans`. For instance the following code provides the same results as the previous one:

```
M <- lsmeans(fit, pairwise~Treatment, lf=TRUE)[[2]] # extract the matrix of pairwise comparisons
summary(glht(fit, linfct=M))
```

Comment: I think you want `fit <- glm(cbind(x,n-x)~0+Treatment, data=dat, family="binomial")` instead.  Note `?glm` requires as an argument `a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures`, not successes and trials.

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way I posted a [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175223/approaches-to-compare-differences-in-means-with-differences-in-proportions) today about group differences that has very low views -- I would much appreciate if you could take a look!  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You just have a binomial experiment, so your confidence interval is given by [Binomial proportion confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). After you calculate them you can figure out if the intervals overlap or not.